# Tracking SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, tracking, skspritenode

I am fairly new to swift and Sprite Kit. I am trying create a simple game using SKSpriteNodes. My game needs to keep track the sequence of the "clicked" nodes as it needs to be processed based on its sequence. I am thinking of creating a list, as the nodes are clicked it will be added to the list. Is this the easiest way? I am thinking that it may consume more memory. My nodes are of the same names. Below is the method I used in adding the nodes in my scene. I need to know the sequence of colored balls clicked.

```
for x in listNodes{
    var ballNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String(color))
    ballNode.name = "ball"

    var point: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    var done: Bool = false

    let randomX = randomRange(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), max: CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)-(ballNode.size.width))
    let randomY = randomRange(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.border.size.height, max: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-ballNode.size.height)

    point = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)

    ballNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    ballNode.position = point

    self.addChild(ballNode)
 }
```

Comment: Using a list/array will not result in substantially increased memory usage, as the list will contain references to the nodes, and not replicate them.

Comment: Agree with ZeMoon; for this sort of operation, the size is negligible.  Note, however, that you will probably want some way to distinguish between the nodes that the player will be clicking on, depending on what you are working on, so you might want to give the nodes an ID value or something, instead of just the name "ball".  You can do this by giving unique names, subclassing SKSpriteNode, or using the *userData* property of SKNode.

Comment: @cc. actually I am using userData for that. thanks! :)